# How can I inject JavaScript file into a WebEngineView page?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols, qtwebengine

I'm adding a script tag to a web page once it's fully loaded in a `WebEngineView`, but it's silently failing somehow.

I inject the script by invoking `webview.runJavaScript` with this code:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "qrc:/jquery-2.1.4.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

That's perfectly standard and to a certain extent it works as expected, i.e., if I view the `html` source of the page, the script tag has indeed been appended to the body.

The problem is that the script isn't being downloaded, or isn't being evaluated, or something. All I know is in the above example the jQuery functions aren't available. If I load a small JavaScript test file with one global variable, that variable's not available either. Changing the url to http instead of qrc and pointing it to a web server makes no difference.

Injecting an `img` tag works fine; the image is loaded and displayed.

But JavaScript is broken somehow. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It looks like the problem is not with the script itself but with what should run the script, is it linked to a button or some other event?

Comment: Thank you for this comment — it sent me down the right path to find a solution. The script was being run from the webview's signal that the page had finished loading. When I broke the script up into three discrete pieces and attached them to three different buttons, it worked, which made me realize it was a problem with asynchronous calls / functions executing too fast. That guided me to the solution I posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem had to do with the asynchronous nature of QML and JavaScript.

I was inserting a script tag to inject jQuery, and then I was calling a function to de-conflict my inserted version of jQuery from whatever version of jQuery might already be in the original page.

But I believe the webview had not finished parsing the inserted jQuery library before my de-conflicting function was called, so it failed. (I'm not very experienced with browser programming or I might have suspected this from the beginning.)

The solution was to insert a script tag with a small bit of JavaScript that inserts jQuery and then sets a timeout to wait 200ms before calling the de-conflict function. Like so:

```
function insertAuhJQuery(){
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "qrc:/jquery-2.1.4.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(s);
window.setTimeout(deConflictJQuery, 200);
}

function deConflictJQuery(){
auh = {};
auh.$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
}

insertAuhJQuery()
```

That works reliably and is acceptable for my purpose.