# When parsing html, do I need to watch out for self closing tags which do not need a solidus, having a closing tag?

Tags: html, parsing, xml-parsing, html-parsing, solidus

There are certain tags in HTML which can be self closing without a solidus. For example:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//www.google.com/favicon.ico">
```

is valid. As such, this is not needed:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//www.google.com/favicon.ico"/>
```

or

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//www.google.com/favicon.ico">foo</link>
```

With these designated tags that do not need the solidus, suppose I come across:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//www.google.com/favicon.ico">
```

Can I assume that a corresponding `</link>` is not present, or will I need to parse the rest of the document and determine that for myself?

Comment: Why do you care whether it is present or not?

Comment: @Alohci If it is present, then I need to look for nested tags. If not present, then I do not need to worry about it.

Comment: You mean nested *elements*. No as rici says, the element will not be nested. If your parser does encounter such an end tag, just throw it away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that the [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) is a pretty intimidating document. But I think it would help you to at least read the [overview about elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#elements-2), following any links which seem relevant.

In particular, you will see there that [`<link>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-link-element) is a [void element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements), about which that section says:

> Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements.

So your second example, in which the text `foo` appears to be the content of the element, is actually deceptive. The element is already closed before the text is encountered, and so the text is content of the parent element (if that is possible). The explicit closing tag is an error, and should be ignored.

Although void elements don't require self-closing in HTML5, they did need to be self-closed in XHTML so it is common to see the `<…/>` syntax.

---

**Note:** *(The following was written when I was under the impression that a precise HTML parser was desired. But I'll leave it in place, even though it might seem a bit agressive, because I think it does have some general advice for people who are (attempting to) write HTML parsers.)*

I'm aware that the referenced standard is a massive document, sometimes confusing, and always complex. That makes writing an HTML parser a challenge. But there are no short cuts. If you want to write a compliant parser, you must read the standard. If you don't care so much about compliance, you shouldn't ask what constructs are compliant (but then you forfeit the right to complain about content creators who produce non-compliant HTML).

Open source parsers exist, also as libraries, so there is no obvious need to write a new one. On the other hand, nothing will teach you more about the task than writing a parser, and I respect anyone with the commitment to do so. I don't think it's a project I would take on at this point. If you want to fo so, start by reading the standard. Also, consider joining the relevant mailing lists or at least following some of the discussions. And best of luck!

**P.S.:** Another useful resource is the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) documentation, linked from the WHATWG document. See, for example, its chapter on the [`<link>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link), particularly the technical specifications section.

Comment: I would just like to state that for the record, I forfeit the right to complain about content creators who produce non-compliant HTML. I am interested in the constructs, sure, but in researching the question, I was told to give up on writing a parser that accurately tracks and signals state changes in an html document, which makes it hard to justify going over every single chapter of the specification. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31141683/2158002 explains the underlying issue I am dealing with, and on the whole, writing this parser is just an attempt to more accurately pinpoint code injection.

Comment: @akiva: Well, fair enough. But you should really be clear about how precisely you intend to parse, or what you believe to be true about the HTML to be parsed which might simplify things. Or something. I was definitely under the impression that you intended a precise parse. I don't quite get the relationship between the answer you linked and your parsing need, but if you're actually working in javascript, can't you just use the DOM instead of parsing? Sorry if I'm completely missing the point.

Comment: Also, you should still at least read the content models section, and the technical specs of tags you're interested in. In the content models section, there are lists of tags of each content type; that's not totally precise but it's some kind of starting point. And sorry if I came off as churlish.

Comment: I am not working in Javascript, but merely inserting it for simple tasks like button pressing. I am using Qt to do this. I'd like to have a Dom Model of html (I am not even sure if that is possible), but the qt class QDomDocument gives me errors when trying to parse HTML, which is to be expected I guess since HTML is not XML. I am trying to figure out if I can use a DOM.